# Find Zombie where id = 1 and store it in a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm taking an interactive lesson Rails For Zombies

There is a database table called (Zombie) and the following fields

```
id  name    graveyard
1   Ash Glen Haven Memorial Cemetary
2   Bob Chapel Hill Cemetary
3   Jim My Fathers Basement
```

1. Is the database table in ruby treated as a Hash?
2. How can i find Zombie where id = 1 and store it in a variable?

I finished TryRuby.Org with no problem. I need to understand this concept
I know how to use the language syntax with no problem just need to understand the simple concept.

Your answer is highly appreciated.
Please no comments, I'm seeking an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Using ActiveRecord, you'll get either an activerecord object or an array of active record objects. Each attribute is then accessible as a method : `Zombie.find(1).name` for example

2) `zombie = Zombie.find(1)`

I highly suggest you follow extra tutorials and take a look here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Good luck!

Comment: Great answer and explanation, railsforzombies webstie doesn't show you what active record is, your link for this guide is so great. but i have a question, how the code would be if i want to use the find method without rails? just using ruby by itself? so i can see what is the class i need to create is it the table name followed by the .find method? how to retrieve a hash instead of array? thanks

Comment: Well you'd have to use some sort of adapter to the DB. For SQL DB, activerecord is what's used in Ruby and Rails, maybe there's other, don't know about that. Or you'd have to write your own adapter but that would take a long time. Ruby by itself doesn't know how to talk to a DB. To retrieve it as a hash, you can anyway do Zombie.find(1)[:name] out of the box if you prefer the hash-style syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of database you are using. If you are using a memory-based key-value store, then yes, it will behave like a hash. Considering you have a 'database table', I will assume the tutorial is for relational databases, and probably ActiveRecord. The point of this paragraph is that there are a lot of different databases that behave differently. For yours, no, the table itself is not a hash.

However, it is similar to a hash in that things are stored with a unique ID (usually an integer starting at 1 and counting up for each record.)

So to save the zombie bob in a variable:

`bob = Zombie.find(2)` or you could do `bob = Zombie.find_by_name('Bob')`

Find uses the id and gets the associated object, which does act like a hash. So for instance:

`bob[:name]` will return `"Bob"`

I suggest you read through the documentation to understand the idea fully of querying a database: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

In rails Models are mapped to the tables these kind of mapping is called object relational mapping if you are using RDBMS(eg mysql, postgresql) or Object mapping if you are using schema less DBMS like mongodb. So basically for your zombies(plural by convention) table there will be a model called Zombie(singular by convention). Depending on the mapper your table type will  vary. Whatever be the mapper any field in a particular record can be accessed by specifying the field after a dot(.) to that object.

z = Zombie.find(1) this will find the row with id = 1, this will return a single record which is definitely not a Hash.

you can use where also for matching some other field like this
zombies = Zombie.where(:name => 'Ash'), this will return a a set of records with name = 'Ash'
which is like an Array but not exactly an Array, you can iterate through the results using each and perform array operations like collect, map.

Comment: How about defining a new Model ? how to write this code? z = Zombie.new  is that correct for defining new model using rails and mysql?

Comment: z = Zombie.new basically creates an object of class Zombie which is a model so if there is a table in your database with the name zombies then 'z' represent a new record in your zombies table. So once you save the object z (z.save) the record will be stored in the db.